# c# Outlook add-in how to run as administrator

Tags: c#, outlook-addin, administration

How can you make a Outlook add-in to run as a administrator?

I have already tried to edit the application manifest , to change the

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
```

to

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

but that did not work.

Comment: Don't think it's possible: an add-in is a dll loaded by the main process (outlook.exe) and the user is a token linked to the process, not to the every loaded add-in. So as long as the user does not start Outolook as admin, also your addin will not have admin privileges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add-ins are not standalone applications. They are run inside of the host application process. So, you will not be able to start only your add-in with admin privileges. Instead, you need to run the host application with addmin privileges if you want to get the add-in run elevated.